# Movie/tv show about people living in separate rooms and communicating through monitors in a post-apocalyptic world

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv, post-apocalyptic

A group of people live individually in these "rooms" and communicate with each other on these monitors. Apparently the world outside is messed up. However one guy thinks there is something else going on and really freaks out. The "group" decides to "blacklist" him and cut off communication with him. When they decide to let him back into the circle he is either dead or missing...? So one of the girls decides to investigate further...leading into that they are all just prisoners and I think she escapes with another guy...

Trying to find the movie and watch it again. Any feedback is helpful, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the site. When did you watch this movie/show, and roughly when do you think it might've been made?

Comment: Ahhhhh, I should have mentioned that. I remember watching it in the last 1-2 years. I think it was made in the last 2-3 years.

Comment: You might be interested in E.M. Forster's [The Machine Stops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Machine_Stops), a short story first published in 1909, where people live alone in rooms underground and communicate via instant messaging and video, with their every need taken care of by machines. The story centers around a woman and her son, who escapes to go "topside". Then...the machine stops.

Answer (score 7):

I'm fairly sure this is *Domain* (2016)

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4694518/

> After a deadly virus wipes out most of humanity, the survivors are
> forced to wait in self-sustaining bunkers with a networked video
> interface for communication, but one by one, they start mysteriously
> disappearing.

All the points you mention match, the timeline is right... It was full of yellow hexagon symbols, and they clearly reused the same set with minimal changes to record everyone one at a time - quite a low budget affair.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: @AshleyScarlet Please remember to accept this answer by clicking the green check mark to its left.