# Post-apocalyptic movie: A man living (alone?) in a bunker, but can talk to people in other bunkers through TVs

Tags: story-identification, movie

I have a vague memory of watching a post-apocalyptical movie on television in the late 90s or early 00's.

A man is surviving, I think alone, in a bunker. There are other people in other bunkers he can communicate with over TVs. One by one, the TVs get cut off as those people die or get killed.

Finally, something digs through the roof of his bunker.

It sounds like what described in [Movie/tv show about people living in separate rooms and communicating through monitors in a post-apocalyptic world](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/243874/movie-tv-show-about-people-living-in-separate-rooms-and-communicating-through-mo), but obviously the movie can't be *Domain* (2016).

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Outer_Limits_(1995_TV_series)_episodes#ep56?

Comment: @Valorum I was thinking of that episode too

Answer (score 22):

Sounds a lot like an episode of "The Outer Limits" (1995-2002), specifically ["Dead Man's Switch"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0667878/), which first aired in 1997.

As I recall the episode, there was a handful of people individually isolated into bunkers positioned at various places around the world, able to communicate only amongst themselves via video links. Each had a "dead man device" which would trigger a doomsday weapon if not attended as required; the weapon would make the planet uninhabitable as a counter to an alien threat. They began to go silent, one at a time, until there was only one left. At the end of the story, the last one remaining could hear digging outside his bunker, but he couldn't know if on the other side of the bunker door was rescue from isolation or an alien invader.

EDIT: I just had the opportunity to re-watch the episode, found I was incorrect about one detail. The episode ends with:

> A video call between the general and the last surviving bunker operator; the general says that the aliens have been defeated by a new weapon and a crew will be dispatched to dig him out; in the meantime, he is to continue pushing the deadman button as long as he can. It is revealed to the audience (not the operator) that the world is in ruins and the general is under alien control - they have invaded. The last survivor does not hear digging - he only knows what he has been told by the general, but is questioning the situation. I was quite sure I recalled an ending scene in which there was an unknown party on the other side of a door, but I could be thinking of either a different episode or an entirely different show. In this episode, there is the sound of drilling, but it occurs at a different bunker; the last survivor is partial witness to the breakthrough at that site, giving him some inclination to ignore the deadman and let the doomsday device go off. The general's final instruction to him leaves him in anguish.

Comment: I enjoyed watching that episode. Near the end, the man in the bunker gets a video message from the general saying that the humans had finally won, to get him to believe the digging is by humans to get him out. However, one of the ending shots shows just the front part of the general is left, with an alien behind what was left and with it controlling him!

Comment: The way I remember it the general was the president of the United States and he was under the control of a brain slug.

Comment: @Muuski As I recall, and the link (from a question comment by Valorum) to [Outer Limits episode #56](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Outer_Limits_(1995_TV_series)_episodes#ep56) also indicates, it was actually a general, not the president of the US, who the soldier was communicating with. However, I watched this episode so long ago that my memory of it is somewhat hazy, but I now believe your description of a "brain slug" (attached to the back of the head & upper part of the body as I recall) is a more accurate description than what I wrote in my earlier comment.